# Publish high resolution drone data as gpkg with mapproxy

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, mapproxy, geopackage, opendronemap

I am currently sitting in front of the problem of publishing high resolution drone data via mapproxy as wmts service.

My approach is the following:

- Calculation of an orthophoto with OpenDroneMap.
- Creation of a geopackage with GDAL:

```
docker run -ti --rm -v D:/Kartendaten:/data osgeo/gdal gdal_translate -of GPKG data/D_Other/Drohne/Drohne_010321_HQ.tif data/D_Other/Drohne/Drohnenaufnahme.gpkg -co TILING_SCHEME=GoogleMapsCompatible -co TILE_FORMAT=JPEG -co QUALITY=75
```

- Inclusion of the gpkg in mapproxy:

```
layers:
   - name: Drohnenaufnahme
     title: Drohnenaufnahme
     sources: [Drohnenaufnahme_cache]
caches:
    Drohnenaufnahme_cache:
        sources: []
        grids: drone_grid
        cache:
            type: geopackage
            filename: D:\Kartendaten\A_Daten\C_Drohne\Drohnenaufnahme.gpkg
            table_name: Drohnenaufnahme
grids:
    drone_grid:
           base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
           tile_size: [256, 256]
           srs: 'EPSG:3857'
            # zoom 0-23
            # See https://gist.github.com/gagan-bansal/db6fb206f61b38f2f1c3
           res: [156543.03392804097,
                78271.51696402048,
                39135.75848201024,
                19567.87924100512,
                9783.93962050256,
                4891.96981025128,
                2445.98490512564,
                1222.99245256282,
                611.49622628141,
                305.748113140705,
                152.8740565703525,
                76.43702828517625,
                38.21851414258813,
                19.109257071294063,
                9.554628535647032,
                4.777314267823516,
                2.388657133911758,
                1.194328566955879,
                0.5971642834779395,
                0.29858214173896974,
                0.14929107086948487,
                0.07464553543474244,
                0.03732276771737122,
                0.01866138385868561]
```

My problem is, if I output the data via ODM in high quality it is not possible to convert the data via GDAL. As soon as I remove the tag TILING_SCHEME=GoogleMapsCompatible, the process runs through, but is no longer readable for Mapproxy due to the COSTUM SCHEME. Also a previous reprojection of the data into the EPSG:3857 does not work.

The whole thing is related to the zoom levels, but I can't find a solution.

Has anyone implemented a similar project or does anyone have a solution that I haven't thought of?